# ¿Cómo puedo generar un jsonarray a partir de un arralyst con java?

Tags: java, mvc, jsonarray

Como puedo generar un *jsonarray* a partir de un *arralyst* y retornarlo a  para que se visualice en una pagina *jsp*, estoy trabajando con *netbens 8.2*, *JQuery* y *json* simple usando el modelo mvc.

Gracias por responder mi pregunta este es mi código  es:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
    List<String>datosproducto=daoproducto.listarproducto();
    JSONObject linea = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray  arreglo = new JSONArray();

    for (int i=0;i<datosproducto.size();i++) {
        linea.put("codprod",i);
        linea.put("descripcion",datosproducto.get(i));
        linea.put("Stock",i+3);

        arreglo.add(linea.toJSONString());
    }
    out.print(arreglo);
}
```

Pero me genera  un *json* así:

```
["{\"descripcion\":\"clavos\"}","{\"descripcion\":\"tornillos\"}","{\"descripcion\":\"martillos\"}"]
```

Y este json no lo leen mi componente vista me da este error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 24

Comment: Bienvenido por favor agrega lo que trataste o investigaste, revisa [ask] y edita tu pregunta,. saludos

Comment: Estoy tratando de llenar un un objeto json array a partir de un arraylist  utilizando el método add   pero solo   aparece último elemento de  arraylist  no sé qué estoy haciendo mal...

Comment: Podrias mostrar algo de codigo para ver que estas intentando hacer.

Comment: gracias por responder mi pregunta este es mi codigo

Comment: Intenta hacer un put al JSONArray en vez de un add